# How to reinstall Ambari Server on a crashed node and migrate the Cluster settings?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

Two of my drives crashed on the Ambari Server node so I have to re-migrate my Ambari Cluster. No real data was lost (due to a different backup strategy) but the configuration files of the node, including Ambari Server configuration, are gone.

Because two drives crashed, I can not access any files from that node anymore (RAID 5).

I am now in the process of reinstalling the Ambari Server on the same node and would like to have my agents seamlessly reconnect to the "new" Ambari Server.

1. Is there a way to migrate the existing Cluster settings to the Ambari Server? I am thinking of Cluster settings that were distributed to the agents or similar.
2. If there is no such way to migrate the cluster, how would I go and install the Ambari Server? Do a fresh install and setup everything again? Will the Ambari agents be able to connect to the "new" Cluster without problems? Note that the Ambari Server will run on the same hostname/ip.

Comment: I just had a similar issue, my Ambari Server node just crashed and I'm trying to re-install it on another node. However I worried with Ambari cluster setup, I fear I'll lost installed service or even data. Were you able to re-install a frash Ambari Server without any issues? What steps did you follow?

Comment: @PierreMerienne i've just re-installed it all the way like the tutorial says. Before that I've used https://community.hortonworks.com/content/idea/138/cleanup-scripts-to-remove-old-hdp-bits.html to get a "clean" install. it worked good for most of my nodes, but one node fails to start hdfs data node service. didnt have the time to check why that happens.